# Document root problem in Eclipse/PHP/Zend

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

Environment:
WindowsXP,
Eclipse Galileo,
Zend Community Edition

(I have configured Eclipse to use the PHP binary in Zend.)

I configured the Apache document root within Zend to point to my Eclipse project folder. So I can use URLs like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost/myscript.php">...
```

But this doesn't work work:

```
<form action="myscript.php">...
```

I get an error saying the file cannot be located at the given server location.

I find this strange because it should refer to the same location as the one with full URL.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Kindly post comments if I should update with more info about my setup.

Comment: When you say "I doesn't work" do you mean you can't browse to http://localhost/myscript.php in your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

To be correct, you're may not refer to the same place. It always depends on the point in the filesystem where you actually are.

```
<form action="/myscript.php">
```

points to the same location.
To be more concrete: Imagine you're running the script `http://localhost/dir/subdir/script.php` with the form action above, you'll one point to

```
http://localhost/dir/subdir/myscript.php
```

and once to

```
http://localhost/myscript.php
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to explain to me. In any case, "/myscript.php" works just as bad as "myscript.php".

Comment: /myscript shall work if the page you actually see is also located at localhost.
You said that the full qualifies URL works. What's the URL of the script that processes the form?